# Broken AC drain fitting

Tags: toyota, ac, matrix, drain

2008 Toyota Matrix with a broken fitting where the ac condensation drain hose attaches to the evaporator housing.  Not being able to run the ac in Texas in the summer is suboptimal, but I'd rather not replace the entire evaporator housing just for the fitting. Any suggestions? (the hose in the picture is the result of a failed attempt to rig a solution).

[image: view from below]

[image: side view]

[image: side view]

[image: outer shield removed]

[image: broken fitting trimmed]

[image: another view]

There's a lot of curvature and not much flat space in the housing.  Access is difficult without removing the passenger seat.  3D printing would be great if I could scan or otherwise get the topology of the housing.  Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Make a plastic plate with spigot to glue into place.

Once repaired avoid repeating the action that broke the original.

Comment: I saw water on the carpet after getting the car detailed.  I went back to the detailer and he denied any responsibility.  So I guess the action to avoid is doing any more business with that detailer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Solar Mike is stating in his answer is spot on ... however, the devil is in the details.

You need to create a new drain tube. Part of it will have the nipple which would attach to the tube. The other part would need to be a flat washer of some type, something you'd attach the nipple to. This washer portion would be about the same size the inner portion of what you are showing in picture one. You want it to fit up in there. You'll need to clean out the broken part within the circular portion, making it as flat as possible. Once all is ready, take some waterproof 2-part epoxy and affix the flat washer portion up where the hole in the evaporator housing, making sure the condensed water has a clear path to run out. You'll also want to put the epoxy into any cracks which may be there. The epoxy serves two purposes, first to affix the new nipple, and secondly to seal anything up. Once all is set and completely cured, re-attach the drain hose to it. Should work as good as it did new.

If you have a 3d printer, you could easily make the part you need.

Comment: What kind of tool would you use to flatten the existing fitting?

Comment: Flatten? use a Dremel or a file or a pair of diagonal cutters ... maybe a chisel? Just work away at it until it is relatively flat and will accept the epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a rubber pipe onto one of these, then support  the large end of this connector in place against the hole.  You may even be able to file the hole to the correct shape so that this connector just screws in slightly-

[image]

Then put plenty of this stuff around it to seal it in place -

[image]

This sealant should stick well to both surfaces and won’t drip off like most glues will.

If it leaks once hard due to leaving a gap somewhere, just add more sealant over it.

Use Tiger Seal, not some random silicone.

You may even be able to get away with just holding the open end of a pipe in place against the hole and using the Tiger seal to glue it in place, then not needing the connector.  Either way, you don’t want the pipe to go inside the casing which would mean that the water would have to rise above the pipe to drain out, keep the pipe or fitting flush to the casing.

Comment: Is Tiger seal available in Austin, Texas?

Comment: @SolarMike everything is available everywhere via the internet.

Comment: @SolarMike It is available in the USA on ebay.com

Comment: So the idea is that the fitting should fit flush to the housing, not leak, and not pull loose. It must be attached with enough strength to stick to the housing when the hose is attached or detached.  Will Tiger Seal be strong enough? Perhaps epoxy to attach and Tiger Seal to seal.

Comment: @jpolache Tiger seal is a very strong adhesive, i have used it many times. It will do a lot better job than epoxy and will not run. Yes, flush to the housing.

Comment: See updated question.